# Cannot insert row into table with foreign key field

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I am working on a PHP application that uses a database extensively. My coworker who set up the database, set up the tables to use foreign keys. Here is the statement I am using:

```sql
INSERT INTO patients (ethnicity, gender)
VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO sessions (patient_id, submitted, age_in_years, video, annotated)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), NOW(), 0, '', FALSE);
```

The first statement works. However, I get the following error with the second statement.

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`<database name>/sessions`, CONSTRAINT `fk_sessions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I have confirmed that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the expected value.

How can I fix this?

Below is how we set up the `sessions` table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `severity` enum('Minimal Symptoms of Autism Spectrum Disorder','Mild-to-Moderate Symptoms of Autism Spectrum Disorder','Severe Symtoms of Autism Spectrum Disorder') default NULL,
  `submitted` datetime default NULL,
  `age_in_years` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video` text NOT NULL,
  `annotated` tinyint(1) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_sessions_1` (`patient_id`),
  KEY `age_in_years` (`age_in_years`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sessions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary details. If you feel you need more, feel free to look at the first version of this post.

Comment: Have you verified that LAST_INSERT_ID() returns an id that exists in the "patient" table ?

Comment: It returns `0`. Any ideas why?

Comment: do you have autocommit set to false in your connection string?

Comment: This may be completely off as I am no MySQL expert at all (the same goes for SQL generally speaking) but could it be because you did not specify the PK in the first statement ? From the reference, it seems that LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last value from the AUTOINCREMENT field (which is usually your PK). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Jeshurun, I call `$database->beginTransaction();` prior to the SQL statements and `$database->commit();` afterward. The rest of my PHP is in the first revision.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, patients.id is indeed the primary key and I tried inserting NULL into that field, but there is no change in results. :(

Comment: I have no MySQL DB to test this but it is in my understanding that you can omit it in the "VALUES()" section and AUTOINCREMENT will do its magic.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, that's what I've been doing. The patients table gets updated just fine.

Comment: What I mean is this: INSERT INTO patients (id, ethnicity, gender)
VALUES (1, 1)
Is this what you meant as well ? (Just to be sure)

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, Well, dang. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` *is* returning the correct value. My mistake. But I still get the same error. :?

Comment: Out of interest, what does `INSERT INTO patients (ethnicity, gender) VALUES (1, 1); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), * FROM patients;` return?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't remember whether you could combine the LAST_INSERT_ID() and * like that. Can you try it separately?

Comment: @Neil, http://pastie.org/pastes/4268894/text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when my coworker added the foreign key, he had a typo in the table name that the foreign key references.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sessions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

should be

```sql
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sessions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patients` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong.

You're attempting to insert a value in `sessons.patient_id` that does not exist in `patients.id`. This is how foreign key constraints work by design. Regardless of whether or not the value of LAST_UPDATE_ID() is what you expect, you need to confirm that the value is valid in `patients.id`.

Example:

```
patients
---------------
id    |    name
---------------
1     |    john
2     |    jane
```

If you try to insert "3" into `sessions.patient_id`, you will get the error you see because that `id` doesn't exist in `patients`.